# HDMI Audio not working on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: nvidia, sound, hdmi

I have an nVidia GeForce and want to send audio output to my television when attaching it via HDMI.. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance

well...

am using an Thomson television and have tried with several desktop envirorments...

Comment: Please include more information, like steps tried, the model of television, the desktop environment, and exactly what is failing. For example, did you check the volume indicator and do you see your TV.

Comment: Might be worth while: install `pavucontrol` it has several more options that sound settings. I used it for 12.10 once to set it correctly and then sound setting did work correctly too.

Comment: pavucontrol doesn't see my hdmi device :-/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in *Sound Settings -> Output* tab, you can select the HDMI output device and the sound will be directed to HDMI. Choose the appropriate profile in the *Mode* dropdown menu.

[image]

Comment: @Takkat - thanks for the correct translation of the menu names and the picture. Mine is not in English and I am using xfce so my own screen shot wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: @Takkat well it isn't there...

Comment: @user1494162 - the HDMI option is not there? If not, probably your nvidia card is not configured properly. Are you using nvidia proprietary drivers or the open source ones? (both should have the HDMI option).

Comment: @Takkat the propietary drivers

Nvidia binary Xorg Driver, Kernel Module and VDPAU library ( nvidia-current )

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to update the sound card driver. to do that go to system settings > additional drivers > select your sound card driver and click on activate (ref bottom right of the window).

hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Just found out the fix for this. Go to **alsamixer** and **unmute S/PDIF**
Here is a [tutorial](http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2012/04/28/how-to-fix-nvidia-hdmi-audio-in-ubuntu-12-04/)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.